# Router DHCP settings while configuring Static IP

Tags: networking, dhcp

[image: Screenshot of router settings]

I've been finding my way around the web trying to configure a Static IP ( on Ubuntu Studio 16.04 Trusty Tahr) but seem to mess up. Is the router setting -to assign a DHCP- as checked in the settings shown correct?

Thanks for any advice on how this can be set up! I'm [following these instructions](http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu-the-proper-way/).

Comment: First of all, you're asking us to check settings on router. This is not Ubuntu question but a router question then, and therefore off topic on this site.

Comment: Your settings are incorrect. I suggest that you set the DHCP range as 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.100. Then use a static IP address of anything above that range, 192.168.1.150, for example.

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on  [SU].

Comment: @chili555 : thanks for that tip. The router assigns addresses from (192.168.1).2 to 50, and the eth0 is set at 101.

Answer (score 0):

A `Static` IP address is set up on the local system, and has nothing to do with the router.

The only time the router gets involved is when you get your IP address via `DHCP`.

They are two separate and distinct ways of assigning an IP address. They do not interoperate.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out for me! So I can leave the box checked as it is and go ahead with the steps in the tutorial-  configure "/etc/network/interfaces" and " etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf" and so on?

Comment: Well, not quite.  Many routers have settings to give specific ip to matched MAC address of client, so if we're talking about giving a machine specific IP then it has to do everything with router's dhcp server. As far as terminology goes, you are correct -  static IP is configured on client.

Comment: @Serg: I'm afraid I don't quite follow. Care to elaborate?

Comment: If the system's IP address is static (assigned through `/etc/network/interfaces`) it's assigned at system startup. If it's assigned via DHCP the system sends a broadcast packet (to `255.255.255.255`) asking if some system (on the local LAN) can attach an IP address to the system's MAC address. The DHCP server responds.

Comment: @Autoresponder The idea is simple - there must be agreement between router and the machine to which it connects on how to do things. Most routers have a DHCP server software, which is responsible for giving out IPs. What you're doing, is telling router "when this MAC address tries to connect to you, give it this specific IP, and don't give that to anyone else". That's  why I said waltinator's not quite correct - in this  case it has everything to do with router config. Another way is to have Ubuntu configured such way, that it only asks for one specific IP. With WiFi this method kinda sucks

Comment: @Autoresponder and this is the main reason why I said your question isn't on topic here. If you were to say "Hey, how do I tell Ubuntu to only ask for this specific IP ?" then this would be OK question here. You router approach is alright, I use that with my TP-Link router. But it's nothing to do with Ubuntu, see ? We can't objectively tell you if your router is alright or not, since we don't have access to same router hardware, plus that hardware doesn't run Ubuntu but something else

Comment: @Serg : Should I ask on another forum or rephrase the question? But thanks regardless- I'm still piecing together networking and ubuntu stuff that might quite be trivial/ self-evident to you! :-)

Comment: @Waltinator: So its a more preferable process to dismiss the router entirely, stick the ethernet cable into the laptop and configure the settings?

Comment: @Autoresponder it's totally OK , I am still learning,too. I can request a moderator to move your post to another site ( and we're not a forum,by the way ) , if you want to deal only with router specifically. Personally, I'd say, the router approach is simplest.  You can also tell Ubuntu to always ask for specific ip , as i mentioned, but it's different from your original post, and probably would be a duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/a/682910/295286

Comment: @Serg: thanks for that link.  I'll get to work with what I've been able to grok from the several comments I've been able to get, and I'll be back to report !